# Views: How to sort in Table format naturally

Tags: 7, views

1. Create view.
2. Select `Format: Table`.
3. Under the Table Settings toggle `Sortable` on.
4. Fields gets arranged/sorted unnaturally 1 2 3 4 40 5 50 51 6 60, etc. both ways ascending and descending.

[image]

The module `Views Natural Sort` does not solve the problem, it works only with fields under `Sort criteria` settings. And it's pretty broken in overall, the option to sort doesn't even appear in my Views.

We want to sort in normal natural way 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install [Views_bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) module.

Then in **views/Format** select **Bootstrap Table**

> Don't forget the Settings

Comment: Isn't this for bootstrap theme only.

Comment: Yes, if you're not using bootstrap theme then try with the settings in table Format
Check Sortable - Default order and default sort